How do I fix this "need arm64e or arm64" error in IntelliJ for Minecraft Forge modding? (MacOS)
Edit: I have an M1 MacBook Air
I have been following a Kaupenjoe tutorial for making a Minecraft Forge 1.18.2 mod but haven't been able to run the runClient task as I keep getting an error:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')) [in thread "Render thread"]

I'm not sure where I can access these files to change and replace them with a version that works for my Mac, and I've tried changing the project SDK to multiple versions of the same Eclipse Temurin 17 JDK for aarch64 but it still won't work. I don't know anything about Java and have limited Minecraft datapack knowledge (not the best for coding in Java but I'm impatient and this was only supposed to be a mod to make some things a little easier in my singleplayer world) so I am clueless and stumped on these errors. It also has been telling me that it can't "initialize the rendering system":
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem

I just recently figured out that the LightWeight Java Game Library is only for x86, which helps me somewhat, but I still don't know how to replace my current x86 version with one that's arm64.
Here's the full lines of error:
Exception in thread "Render thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:39)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:106)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:77)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23)
    at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher@1.0.0/cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/fmlloader@1.18.2-40.2.10/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.lambda$launchService$0(ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.java:24)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.SystemReport.setDetail(SystemReport.java:65)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.fillSystemReport(Minecraft.java:2284)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.fillReport(Minecraft.java:2277)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:178)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')) [in thread "Render thread"]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2394)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1970)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem

    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/zs/9xkpdhg532l8zcrkm3sqmf480000gp/T/lwjgleversbergb26/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/liblwjgl.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')) [in thread "Render thread"]

    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:152)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:116)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:97)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.MemoryTracker.<clinit>(MemoryTracker.java:8)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.BufferBuilder.<init>(BufferBuilder.java:48)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.Tesselator.<init>(Tesselator.java:19)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.Tesselator.<init>(Tesselator.java:23)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.Tesselator.<clinit>(Tesselator.java:11)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.<clinit>(RenderSystem.java:46)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:167)
    ... 13 more

> Task :runClient FAILED

Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


It seems to demand a Mac with an M chip, not the Intel chip your Mac has.

I was going to suggest the exact opposite, that he's downloaded an x86/x64 library that won't link on his M chip.  Perhaps the OP should tell us which Mac he has.

Whoops, sorry. I have an M1 chip in my laptop.

 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')) probably the native library is x86_64 then. You need the version for your architecture.
